# multiprocessing and tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

In my class, I draw Tkinter elements, I press the right button and there is a long download of data from the Internet. At this time, the window of my program in Windows freezes=(
I 'm trying to do this:

```
def get_data_orders_production(url):
  print(2)
  ...
  return [1, 2, 3, 4 ...]

class MyApp():
  def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    
  ...
  
  def check_process(self, p):
    if p.is_alive():
      print(1)
      self.root.after(2000, lambda p=p: self.check_process(p))

  def create_page_tk(self, flag):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_data_orders_production, args=(self.url))
    p.start()
    self.check_process(p)
    p.join()
```

When starting the function: "create_page_tk" - print(1) and print(2) at the same time, then the recursion does not work! Also I do not know how to return the value from the "get_data_order_production" function.

Comment: Calling `p.join()` will block the main application until the process completes.

Comment: also it is better to use `self.root.after(2000, self.check_process, p)`, you don't need the `lambda`, you can pass arguments that need to be passed to the function as arguments to the `after` method

Answer (score 0):

Calling `p.join()` will block the main application until the process completes.

Also you need [Inter-Process Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to exchange data across processes, like [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

```py
import multiprocessing

...

def get_data_orders_production(url, queue):
    print(2)
    # ...
    # return required data via queue
    queue.put([1, 2, 3, 4])

...

class MyApp():
  def __init__(self, root):
      self.root = root
      # create a queue for exchanging data between processes
      self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

  #...

  def check_process(self, p):
      if p.is_alive():
          print(1)
          self.root.after(2000, self.check_process, p)
      else:
          if not self.queue.empty():
              # get and show data from queue
              print(self.queue.get())

  def create_page_tk(self, flag):
      p = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_data_orders_production, args=(self.url, self.queue))
      p.start()
      self.check_process(p)
      # don't call p.join()

...
```